# AWS lambda return wrong output

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a basic lambda function try to list all the S3 buckets.
The code is as below

```
import json
import boto3

s3=boto3.resource("s3")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket_list=[]
    for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
        print(bucket)
        bucket_list.append(bucket.name)
    return{
        'statuscode': 200,
        "body" : bucket_list
    }
```

When I did test, it passed the test but the output is not what I expected.
Output as below

```
Test Event Name
listS3Event

Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 7f9cd1ef-2907-4ce1-8951-b410dfb116ab Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 7f9cd1ef-2907-4ce1-8951-b410dfb116ab
REPORT RequestId: 7f9cd1ef-2907-4ce1-8951-b410dfb116ab  Duration: 1.38 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 49 MB

Request ID
7f9cd1ef-2907-4ce1-8951-b410dfb116ab
```

It looks like it was run with the default code, but I could not figure out where did I do wrong.
Any suggestion.

Comment: Have you deployed your changes to the lambda?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using api gateway to fire the lambda. In that case, not only should you deploy the lambda, you should also create a new `deployment` in api gateway.
[see here for more details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-deployments.html)